# How can I make text that is bigger than its wrapper be invisible

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I want this for an animation where after a delay, the text will expand. I have this done, but the text that I wanted to appear doesn't show up and so I tried using the word-wrap css property, but there were no options to make the text invisible if it was bigger than the container. What could I do for this to happen? I have tried searching for other posts asking the same question, but I haven't found any.

Here is a fiddle, jsfiddle.net/wm3n7g58/20.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this css, `white-space: nowrap;` and on the wrapper `overflow:hidden;`

```css
h1{
  color:red;
  background: gold;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Calibri;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 100vw; /*STOPS THE TEXT FROM MOVING*/
  
}

.wrapper{
  animation-name: animation;
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-delay: 0s;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow:hidden;
}

@keyframes animation{
  
  0%{
    width: 0px
  }
  100%{
    width:100%
  }
}
```

```html
<div class = "wrapper">
  <h1>
  This is a Wrapper 
  </h1>
</div>
```

Comment: That didn't work. Here is a fiddle, https://jsfiddle.net/wm3n7g58/20/. I don't want this to happen where the text is seen from the start, I want it to expand in how much text is seen as it's container expands.

Comment: I have update my answer.
1) you have 'no-wrap' it should be 'nowrap'
2) add 'overflow hidden to the wrapper to hide overflowing content

Comment: By the way if you want the text to tay in the middle and not move then add a width to the h1 I will update answer